# trying to ssh from 2018 macbook to mac mini; getting error "pledge: filesystem full" and "shell request failed on channel 0"

Tags: macos, terminal, mac-mini, ssh, monterey

Been having a fun day. I upgraded both my mac mini (intel, 2018) and my macbook (intel, 2018) to Monterey and also upgraded openssl and whatever else brew was willing to upgrade. I used to be able to ssh from my macbook to the mac mini with an ssh key I had copied over. Now the spooky stuff:

- my password to authenticate to the mac mini is different from my user's password on the mac mini
- this error message, when I try `ssh -Tv username@mac.mini.net`:

```
Authenticated to mac.mini.net ([ipaddress]:22) using "password".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
shell request failed on channel 0
```

- I also get `exec failed on channel 0` when I try to copy over an ssh key.

I don't know if I should nuke the whole setup (I need the ssh keys I have to log into other stuff though - I can ssh into other machines without any trouble) - tutorials on safely nuking my ssh setup are welcome if y'all think that is the case. Any advice on what's going on / what to try next would be very helpful.

Comment: It seems like you'll need to free up some disk space on the mini.

Comment: the mini has about 400gb of free disk space currently

Answer (score 6):

What version of ssh are you using on the client and the server? You can find out using `ssh -V`.

Also, for your next step, try `ssh -vvv` to show all 3 levels of debug mode. It might indicate why it is failing.

BTW, the `debug1: pledge: filesystem full` message actually has to do with the HostKeys in the UserKnownHostsFile. See UpdateHostKeys: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html and client_loop() https://fossies.org/linux/openssh/clientloop.c.

Comment: Most importantly, `debug1: pledge: filesystem full` does not indicate a problem, (especially not with the amount of free space available!) it's just notes what mode the client is going to request ("pledge") to use with the server.